# Replace Maven properties in pom.xml via command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, properties, pom.xml

I want to replace a Maven property in a `pom.xml` file with a command line call via some Maven plugin.

```
<properties>
    <my.property>ISO-8859-1</my.property>
<properties>
```

Do you know of a plugin which is able to do that?

The [versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) takes very long since it checks whether some dependency is available. Besides that it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You don't need a Maven plugin, just do `-Dmy.property=UTF-8` on the command line

Comment: If you are trying to modifying the pom file via maven :-), then its not possible

Comment: Without more clarification, this is a dup of [How can I update a property in a Maven POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25034556/86967)

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is add the following when running maven on the command line

```
-Dmy.property=propertyValue
```

Comment: What if I wanna use a file?