# maven property is not overrided with -dParam.version

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

When i exeute:
`mvn -Dparam.version=9 help:effective-pom | clip`
in the command line on `Windows 10` i get all over this clip only:

```
<properties>
      <param.version>4</param.version>
</properties>
```

which is the old version.
How can i force to change this param?

In the cmd:

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.4
```

Froms poms:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT:**
I use this property to set depedency version for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>c-api/artifactId>
    <version>${param.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

inside `c-api` we can see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>x</groupId>
        <artifactId>c</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>c-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>c-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>p-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>x</groupId>
            <artifactId>f-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `mvn -Djava.version=9 ...`?

Comment: @SteveC no - let's suggest the name of parameter is `param` it is not related to `java` version. From which version is this `overriding` feature avaiable ?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130388/replace-maven-properties-in-pom-xml-via-command-line that should work, so maybe there is something you do differently?

Comment: Sorry, the presence of the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration is completely irrelevant then. Please add the section of your pom where `${param.version}` is evaluated.

Comment: I added an example where i use my param

Comment: Another thing is that `c` pom is from `.m2/repository` right now.

Comment: According to what you have above, the x:c:4 artifact is in fact a parent pom, so the dependency example you added will fail because it does not refer to a jar. Are you trying to parameterise the version of the parent of the x:c-api:4 artifact?

Comment: I'm sorry  - i try to change childs version to be excact: `<artifactId>c-api/artifactId>`
my bad - i'm sorry. I fixed the question. `c-api` is child of `c`.
This was a `typo`. I meant before `c-api`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need use `-Dparam.version` instead `-dParam.version`.

If

```
<properties>
    <param.version>4</param.version>
</properties
```

is defined in the `xxx.pom` file, you are not allowed to **change** it using command line, while you are free to **override** it. And in this case, though the value is still `4` in the pom file, others which refer it by `${param.version}` will pick `9`.

Comment: that's intresting. Still the main pom has old version though and this maybe my issue.

Comment: @yami This might help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708738/how-to-get-a-command-line-property-to-overwrite-a-maven-property

Comment: yeah i got a lot of `${param.version}` in my project i edited the question. The question is that stuff `X` reads the old value somewhere. I do not see elsewhere  `param.version` set to `4` manually (only in the properties of main pom once).

Comment: `First, you need use -Dparam.version instead -dParam.version.` yeah, I use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the incorrect place when checking if your command line parameter has been correctly applied.

If you entered the command `mvn -Dparam.version=9 help:effective-pom` then you should see your *dependency* version evaluated correctly.

Where your pom has

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>c-api</artifactId>
    <version>${param.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
```

the output of the command will display

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>c-api</artifactId>
    <version>9</version>
</dependency>
...
```

If you just run `mvn help:effective-pom` you will see

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>x</groupId>
    <artifactId>c-api</artifactId>
    <version>4</version>
</dependency>
...
```

with the version specified in the pom properties displayed instead.

Comment: That's an answer for an upvote. Still i checked in `war` from `target` folder in `tomcat/lib` and some versions are old. If i type newer version in main pom manually (like `9`) then i got good versions in war from `target` in `tomcat/lib` the core of my issue is not resolved by this answer and as i posted in the question i tried to run `mvn -Dparam.version=9 help:effective-pom` not `help:effective-pom` to check faster versions. I want the versions to be the same when changing param version with `mvn clean install` just like in the case when i change version manually in the main pom.

Comment: So you understood it clearly:
1) If I change version manually to let's say `9` in main pom - everything is ok, all libs from `war` file located in `target` folder are ok.
2) When i try to change versions by additional param to `mvn clean install` like `mvn -Dparam.version=9` the versions in the libs are not ok - they are still `4` - the old ones.

Comment: If it's not working for you then there is something else going on. I have tested this. Note that you cannot modify the dependency versions if they have not been defined as a property in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean? I have `<param.version>4</param.version>` as `property` and use it in depedency `version` like `<version>${param.version}</version>`. The `c-api` is only placed as `<artifactId>`