# How do/can I change the value of a property in my pom.xml via commandline or mvn command?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an internal library and I put the actual version in the property section.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <springfox-version>2.5.0</springfox-version>
    <common.version>6.0.3-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
</properties>
```

I want to automate the release process so in my Jenkins pipeline script, I would like to be able to run a command and update the 'common.version' to whatever the user entered as parameter.

When I run:

```
mvn versions:update-property -Dproperty=common.version -DnewVersion=[6.0.3] -DallowSnapshots=true
```

I get:

```
[INFO] Property ${common.version}: Leaving unchanged as 6.0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update a property in a Maven POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034556/how-can-i-update-a-property-in-a-maven-pom) (AFAICT you will probably want to use the second most-upvoted answer)

Comment: im on mvn 3.3, when i run setproperty, i get error, something something could not find goal

Comment: Hmm, maybe `versions:set` instead? https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html ; set-properties doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: the set will change the projects vresion, not the specific property that i want :(