# Modify properties tag in POM.xml file from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have following properties in pom.xml file :-

```
<properties>
<cm_java_home>C:/Java/jdk1.8.0-102/bin</cm_java_home>
</properties>
```

But, I need to change this during building job from Jenkins, and it should look like as given below:-

```
<properties>
<cm_java_home>/home/abc/Java/jdk-1.8.0-102/jre</cm_java_home>
</properties>
```

How to modify my properties tag in pom.xml file using Jenkins job configuration ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update a property in a Maven POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034556/how-can-i-update-a-property-in-a-maven-pom)

Comment: Hi Fabian, Thank you for your answer. I resolved my issue by using:-    mvn clean install -Dcm_java_home="/home/abc/Java/jdk-1.8.0-102/jre"

Comment: Then please add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, to modify any property of pom.xml file, use -D=value.

For instance, in my case,

I used the following:-

```
mvn clean install -Dcm_java_home="/home/abc/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre"
```